# How to print first word from a file separeted by a tab line?

Tags: java, flatfilereader

i am trying to read a file and print only the first number from each line . i have tried to use split, but it never return correct result , it just print entire contetn as below in the table. Any help would be highly appreciated

> ```
> **thats my file** 
>
>  40    3  Trottmann
>  43    3  Brubpacher
> 252    3  Stalder
> 255    3  Leuch
> 258    3  Zeller
> 261    3  Reolon
> 264    3  Ehrismann
> 267    3  Wipf
> 270    3  Widmer 
>
> **expected output** 
>  40
>  43
> 258
> 261
> 264
> 267
> 270
> ```

**output**

> ```
> 258
> 261
> 264
> 267
> 270
> ```

public class word {

```
            public static void main(String[] args) {
                
                // Create file
                File file = new File("/Users/lobsang/documents/start.txt");
    
                try {
                    // Create a buffered reader
                    // to read each line from a file.
                    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                    String s;
    
                    // Read each line from the file and echo it to the screen.
                    s = in.readLine();
                    while (s != null) {
                        
                          
                        
                        System.out.println(s.split("\s")[0]);
                    
                        
                        s = in.readLine();
                    }
                    
                    // Close the buffered reader
                    in.close();
    
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                    // If this file does not exist
                    System.err.println("File not found: " + file);
    
                } catch (IOException e2) {
                    // Catch any other IO exceptions.
                    e2.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
    
        }
```

Comment: The Regex in your `split` method is technically correct, but you need to escape the backslash in java. So the fixed line would be: `System.out.println(s.split("\\s")[0]);`

Comment: Thanks it did worked .. can you please looks once again at my output .. made some changes..   it output just empty  for all number which has digit less than three .  may be because of initial space instead of number .. how can i update my expression so that it display all number including 1 and 2 digit numbe r

Comment: I added an answer down below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I already answered in the comments, you need to escape the backslash in java.
Furthermore, you can `trim()` the string before splitting it, which removes leading and trailing whitespaces. This means, it will also work with two digit or one digit numbers. So what you should use is:

```
System.out.println(s.trim().split("\\s")[0]);
```

Comment: if you could .. can you please have a look at my this other issue :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64858171/how-to-read-two-text-file-into-a-class-object-and-write-them-to-one-text-file?noredirect=1#comment114672120_64858171

Answer (score 1):

You need to double backslash for the backslash to be read, so do this:

> `System.out.println(s.split("\\s")[0]);`

instead of:

> `System.out.println(s.split("\s")[0]);`

Answer (score 1):

To match a character having special meaning in regex, you need to use a escape sequence prefix with a backslash (\). Escape sequence for white space is `\s` so you need to replace `"\s"` with `"\\s"`